# Why visor got "empty topology" after open?

Tags: ignite

Guys

I deploy a 6 nodes ignite for spark job. it works fine. However, when i hope to use the visor to do administration, i can not see the topology.

here is the config file.
[image]

And, when I enter the visor console, and open the config file. I encountered the "Empty topology"

[image]

[image]
any suggestion? how can i see the topology? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys

I found the root cause, I use Static IP Based Discovery, i just config the IP Address List.

And I ran the visor on one of the nodes, so the visor uses port 47501, but the config file with static ips did not contain this server:port. Finally, this visor can not join the ignite cluster, and can not communicate with them.

use this to fix.
      172.16.59.141:47500..47509

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything suspicious in your config.

I want to see logs from all nodes: 6 servers nodes and Visor node.

To get logs from Visor, please, run

```
./bin/ignitevisor.sh -v
```

To get logs from server nodes see `<ignite_home>/work/logs`.

Could you please zip all these logs and provide link on them (on any file sharing).

Also, I don't think any reason why you need to run visor with sudo rights. Could you please run Visor without sudo.